# Implicit none, implicit conversion

Tags: fortran, fortran90

How to convert the following code which use `implicit none`

```
module kinds
    use iso_fortran_env, only : real64, int32 
    implicit none 
    integer, parameter :: wp = real64, iwp = int32 
end module kinds
```

to use `implicit`. I tried,

```
module kinds
    use iso_fortran_env, only : real64, int32 
    implicit integer (w, i)
    parameter :: wp = real64, iwp = int32 
end module kinds
```

but it does not work.

My problem is how to declare a parameter using the `implicit` statement in Fortran90.

Comment: Why do you have the impression that _it does not work_?

Comment: Generally I would use the following quote here: _[Implicit none, and carry on!](https://milancurcic.com/2019/10/17/implicit-none-and-carry-on.html)_

Comment: "but it does not work. " what doesn't work? Do you get an error? Why use the `IMPLICIT INTEGER ` statement at all, just always use the `IMPLICIT NONE`, make it explicit and readable.

Comment: You probably would ned something like: `parameter (wp = real64, iwp = int32 )`

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Indeed misread the comment, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **General comment:** Using `implicit none` makes debugging life easier!
>  Just [***Implicit none, and carry on!***](https://milancurcic.com/2019/10/17/implicit-none-and-carry-on.html)

---

Due to the implicit statement you define, which is correct, you mix *type-declaration statements* with *parameter statements*. I mention this because you use the token `::` in your parameter statement.

**type-declaration statement:**

> R801 `declaration-type-spec [ [ , attr-spec ] ... :: ] entity-decl-list`
>
> **<sub>source: [F2018 standard section 8.2](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/18/18-007r1.pdf)</sub>**

You can declare your type with possible attributes, such as `PARAMETER` and the token `::` which is only optional when no attributes are defined.

**`PARAMETER`-statement:**

> The `PARAMETER` statement specifies the `PARAMETER` attribute (8.5.13) and the values for the named constants in the list.
>
> R851 parameter-stmt is `PARAMETER ( named-constant-def-list )`
> R852 named-constant-def is `named-constant = constant-expr`
>
> **<sub>source: [F2018 standard section 8.6.11](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/18/18-007r1.pdf)</sub>**

So you notice immediately that the token `::` is only optional in the *type-declaration statement* and not in the *parameter statement*.

There are now two possible options to write the module:

**via type-declaration:**

```
module kinds
    use iso_fortran_env, only : real64, int32 
    implicit integer (w, i)
    integer, parameter :: wp = real64, iwp = int32 
end module kinds
```

but then why would you use the implicit declaration here, you still have to state it is an `integer`. So `implicit none` would just be as fine, or just the implicit statement and just write nothing.

**via `PARAMETER`-statement:**

```
module kinds
    use iso_fortran_env, only : real64, int32 
    implicit integer (w, i)
    parameter (wp = real64, iwp = int32)
end module kinds
```

Comment: Great, explanations and very interesting discussion up there. Thank you.